# How to create a 'dummy' DATETIME field for QGIS timemanager?

Tags: qgis, expression, timemanager

We have several 'time-aware' datasets, but the dates are stored as YEAR (2017), SCHOOLYEAR (20172018), etc. rather than a true DATETIME value.

In order to animate these datasets, is it possible to create a dummy DATETIME value using a virtual field in QGIS?

I've tried so far to create a virtual field using the following expression:

```
to_datetime(LEFT("SCHOOLYEAR",4) || '-' || '10' || '-' || '01')
```

Which looks correct:

[image]

...though in the attribute table there is an added T - which might be acceptable based on the formats I get in the error below...

[image]

But when I apply the layer to the timemanager, I get this error:

[image]

Any thoughts on what format / expression I should be using given my inputs?

Comment: Without the to_datetime(): If I use a datetime field type for the virtual field, I get the same error as above. If I use a char field, I get an error that the virtual field doesn't exist...

Comment: @Kazuhito there is no option for STRING outright, just the three text type fields...

Comment: @Kazuhito yes, doesn't seem to be working...

Comment: ...it is strange and I cannot reproduce this error. A text field like `2009-10-01` works just fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me some time to reproduce the error, sorry...

[image]

The error (upper right) came from wrong choice of the `Start time`(hence also `End time`). in the Time manager's **Settings**. We have to select DATETIME field. It can be either Date, Datetime, Text(string) types (as far as the format is acceptable to Time manager).

[image]

Your original data as shown in your question should work fine, too.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm doing everything correct so far - not sure why I'm getting this error!

Comment: @DPSSpatial Yes, very much weird...

Comment: Still didn't figure this out, but accepting this as the answer.